# XCode/iOS: Signed With Invalid Entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode is building my app successfully, but it gives me this error immediately after the build is completed:

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
>
> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
>   Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those
>   specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

I have read through a few other stack overflow threads on  here, which lead me the try the following, all of which ended up unsuccessfully:

1. Ensured the same bundle identifier was provided in both the .plist file and the under "Packaging" in "Build Settings".
2. Restarted Xcode.
3. Ensured my Device ID was properly linked in my developer account.
4. Deleted my .entitlements file and allowed Xcode to automatically regenerate it after clicking "Fix Issue" in "Capabilities".

One thing that I think might be causing it is that my provisioning profile contains the following list of items:

```
Get-task-allow, 
Aps-environment, 
com.apple.developer.team-identifier, 
Application-identifier, 
Keychain-access-groups
```

But my entitlements file, even when automatically generated, only includes the `aps-environment`key.

I would gladly enter all the aforementioned keys manually, but I am not sure what kind of values they can take--I am willing to try a list of different values, but I can't seem to find this information on Apple's docs.

If anyone knows of such a guide, I would be grateful. If anyone also has any other suggestions to try, I am open to that as well.

EDIT: I followed Apple's Entitlement Troubleshooting guide, dowloaded my provisioning profile, obtained the dict of entitlements from it (with the exact values), and pasted it into my .entitlements file--and somehow, I am still getting the same error...

EDIT #2: If it is relevant, I am code signing manually, by downloading my provisioning profile directly from my dev account.

EDIT #3: I am only using three entitlements: Push notifications and the default Game Center and In-App Purchases. I have made sure that the push notifications are configured properly--development, but I am not sure what to do with the other two (I am not actually using them, they are just set by default).